# Video recording format .3gp not supported in Samsung 4.2.2 device

Tags: java, android, video-recording

I've written code to save the video in .3gp format.

But it's not working on some devices (Samsung 4.2.2). How to record in .3gp format in samsung 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can build ffmpeg library to work with images for Android device and work with it.
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html